# Keep playing sound on macOS even during sleep

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I'm playing sound using the following code:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mysound", ofType: "wav") {
        do {
            sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.numberOfLoops = -1
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            print("Could not find file")
        }
}
```

It is working, however if I close the lid, the device goes to sleep and sound stops.
How can I keep playing sound when the lid is closed?

Comment: I think the user has to allow this in settings

Comment: Do you know how?

Comment: I’m Mac settings you can disable sleep when the lid is down. Not at my computer to check just now.

Comment: I googled it, there is no such option :(

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to prevent your MacBook from sleeping when the lid is closed:

1. Use a utility like [Fermata](https://github.com/iccir/Fermata).
2. Connect an external display.